Can Koin inject view models with a key, like ViewModelProvider.get()?
Is there an equivalent to this in Android Koin?
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(fragment, factory).get(
    key = "unique_key_goes_here", 
    modelClass = MyViewModel::class.java
)

That is, I want to inject my view model with a key value such that injecting with the same key (in the same lifecycle) always returns the same view model instance, and calling it with a different key returns a different instance.
